# How to run a jar file through Jenkins?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jenkins

I am trying to execute `Jarfile` through `Jenkins`. I succeeded in creating a `Jar` file through `Jenkins`, but I don't know how to do it after I make it. How can I run and test a project?

**Project Settings in Jenkins**

[image]

[image]

**init_server.sh**

```sh
echo "> Check the currently running spring server pid "
 CURRENT_PID=$(ps -ef | grep java | grep zzazan* | awk '{print $2}')
echo "$CURRENT_PID" 
 if [ -z $CURRENT_PID ]; then
echo "> No applications are currently running and will not be shut down." 
else
echo "> kill -9 $CURRENT_PID" 
kill -9 $CURRENT_PID
sleep 10
fi
 echo "> Deploy new spring application!!" nohup java -jar /root/jenkinsproject/deploy/testjpaproject.jar >> /root/jenkinsproject/logs/springtestprojectSys.log &
```

> NOTE: This setting was followed by a blog post, and this is the `JPA`
>   project. Use `build.gradle` and `application.yml`.

Comment: Any specific error you are getting in the jenkins job pipline?

Comment: Why do you want to run it with a shell script? If you want to test it use Junit

Comment: @chakradharkasturi No, no errors are visible.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli As far as I know, if it's made in war files, I can run the war after the build. So I want to execute jarfiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run commands to be executed in shell.
Pass the java -jar cmd in *Execute Shell* to run the jar file after it is created.
Hope this helps!

Check this out -> https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

Comment: Did you try running this ```nohup java -jar /root/jenkinsproject/deploy/testjpaproject.jar >> /root/jenkinsproject/logs/springtestprojectSys.log &``` in the Execute shell?

Comment: So, there aren't any logs in the nohup file? Maybe try running without the nohup see what comes up in the jenkins server logs.

Comment: The log remains.

Comment: Your help was appropriate.